# Connect to Dropbox API using intents in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, android-intent, dropbox, firemonkey

Recently I have got message from `Dropbox`:

> Your Android app currently processes the OAuth app authorization flow inside a web view, instead of the system browser.

So I have to change the `OAuth` app authorization from `TWebBrowser` to `Intents`.

So here is my question. How can I get the data back from system browser and how to close the browser after authorization is finished?

I had tried with code below but I got `“Cancelled”` message only when I close the system browser.

My Code:

```
procedure TfrmmDropBoxIntent.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Intent: JIntent;
    ResolveInfo: JResolveInfo;
begin
try
    sURL :=
      'https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize' +
      '?response_type=token' +
      '&client_id=' + cloudDropBoxID +
      '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/';

      FMessageSubscriptionID := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageResultNotification, HandleActivityMessage);

      Intent := TJIntent.Create;
      Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
      Intent.setData(StrToJURI(sURL));

      ResolveInfo := SharedActivity.getPackageManager.resolveActivity(Intent, 0);
      if ResolveInfo  nil then
        SharedActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent, FRequestCode);
  finally
  end; 
end;

procedure TfrmmDropBoxIntent.HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
  if M is TMessageResultNotification then
    OnActivityResult(TMessageResultNotification(M).RequestCode, TMessageResultNotification(M).ResultCode,
      TMessageResultNotification(M).Value);
end;

function TfrmmDropBoxIntent.OnActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode: Integer; Data: JIntent): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.Unsubscribe(TMessageResultNotification, FMessageSubscriptionID);
  FMessageSubscriptionID := 0;

  if RequestCode = FRequestCode then
  begin
    //Get Data? 

    if Assigned(Data) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(JStringToString(Data.getDataString));
    end;

    if ResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_OK then
    begin
      if Assigned(Data) then
      begin
        //Get Data...  How ?
      end;
    end
    else if ResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_CANCELED then
    begin
      //Cancel
    end;
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```